# Can't edit or delete rows from SQL database with Python 3.11 and pypyodbc

Tags: python-3.x, pypyodbc

> I am using python 3.11, tkinter, and Pypyodbc 1.3.6 to interact with sql.  I can enter new rows >and read existing rows, but I can't delete or edit rows within the database.  I don't believe it >is pypyodbc because I was able to delete rows in another project with the same Python code.  >Now, everything I try gives me an error related to the variable I'm using to set the where >clause in the sql statement.

> After trying to directly edit a selected table row, with no luck, I decided to delete the >existing row and enter the whole row again with a different quantity value.  This worked on my >first script.
> So, I used this code to pull data from the correct table:

```
    conn = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''select boxID, boxLength, boxWidth, boxHeight, boxQuantity, boxRow 
    from boxInventory where boxQuantity > 0 order by boxLength, boxWidth, boxHeight''')
    boxSelectionRow = cursor.fetchall()
```

> I then run a where loop to find the smallest set of dimensions which meet the requirements.  At >the end of the loop, I put: `boxSelectionRow.pop(0)`
> Finally, I run the block of code to delete the selected row in the table:

```
   
    boxRow = boxSelectionRow[0][5]
    conn = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''delete from boxinventory where boxSelectionRow = ?''', boxRow)
    cursor.commit
```

> In the first script I did this, it worked.  That was a simple call from one database, interpret >the values, and place in a second database, with no direct input from user.  This time, I am >using tKinter as a GUI.  I can add and read rows, but I can't edit or delete.  I keep running >into: TypeError: Params must be in a list, tuple, or row.  Is this an issue between tKinter and >pypyodbc?

Comment: Typo: `cursor.commit` should be `cursor.commit()`.  As the error said, it should be `cursor.execute('''delete ...''', (boxRow,))` instead.

Comment: i would avoid using pop inside a for loop. Use 


```Python3


for i in range(len(items)): 

    item = items[i]

    # do something if

 
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work :

```
boxRow = boxSelectionRow[0][5]
conn = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''delete from boxinventory where boxRow = ?''', [boxRow])  # Note the square brackets around boxRow
cursor.commit()
```